# Convergence of Euler's Method To Solve Differential Equations

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, eulers-method

if we use backward euler's method to solve following differential equation , for which values of h the method is convergent?

$y^{\prime}(t)=\lambda y(t)+g(t), \quad y\left(t_{0}\right)=y_{0}, \quad \lambda<0$

assume values of |$\lambda$| is big.

I tried to solve equation

$y^{\prime}(t)-\lambda y(t)=g(t)$

Where the above equation is linear we have

$y(t)=e^{\lambda t}\left[\int_{0}^{t} g(x) d x+C\right]$
Now I don’t know how I can find values of h that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} e_{n, h}=0$

Comment: Hi! Can you show your work in the problem? What have you tried? what are you stuck on?

Comment: i explained in my question box. please check again.

Comment: @MehrabRajabi Your question does not make sense... The method is convergent if the numerical solution approaches the exact solution as $h \to 0$. Maybe you want to know about stability?

Comment: The (relative) error can be written as power series in $(λh)$. The leading error term is proportional to $λ^2th$. So if you keep $λh$ small, the relative error will grow as multiple of $λt$. Or you can keep the error about constant relative to $λ$ by keeping $λ^2h$ at about the same small value.

Comment: Thank you , your help was very useful .